# RestSharp not connecting to HP ALM

Tags: api, rest, restsharp, alm

This is my first try with RestSharp & HP ALM Rest API . Everything seems ok to me in code but still getting unauthorized error in response.

Any clue , where am i missing ??

```
var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://abc:8080/qcbin/");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("poprawem", "abc`enter code here`");
            client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

            var request2 = new RestRequest("rest/domains/Projects/projects/Newgen/defects/");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request2);
```

Error i am getting is

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /qcbin/rest/domains/Projects/projects/Newgen/defects/. Reason:
<pre>    Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append '?login-form-required=y' to the url you tried to access.</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need authenticate and create session first.

```cs
var almServerUri = new Uri("http://alm.server.com/qcbin/");

var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = almServerUri;
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("poprawem", "abc`enter code here`");
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

var authRequest = new RestRequest("authentication-point/authenticate");
var authResponse = client.Get(authRequest);

var createSessionRequest = new RestRequest("rest/site-session");
var createSessionResponse = client.Post(createSessionRequest);
try
{
    //...........
    //Do what you need here
    //............
}
finally
{
    var closeSessionRequest = new RestRequest("rest/site-session");
    var closeSessionResponse = client.Delete(createSessionRequest);
}
```